# Firebase friendships node how to display user data with only uid

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

When showing a users friend list with this db structure:

```
friendships:
 user1
    - user3: true
    - user4: true
 user2
    - user1: true 
    - user5: true
```

What would be the best way to display the users data from their users node based off their uid (which is actually the key in my example rather than userX).

So for **user1**, his friend list should have **user3** and **user4** displaying in a list with their *username* and *profilePic* for example... I can’t wrap my head around a good solution rather than downloading the whole users node and finding a match for the uids to list out (which would result in a lot of unwanted $$$ downloads)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate table with user data.

```
users:
  user1:
    username: bob
    email: xx@yy.com
    etc.
  user2:
    username: jane
    email b@a.com
```

Then, you can query the users object by uid like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').child('user1').once("value", snapshot => {
    let userData = snapshot.val();
    let username = userData.username;
}
```

And do that for each friend, therefore you are only downloading the data for each friends, rather than every user.

Comment: Just got it working my man - thank you! I already had the users node set up, what I did was run a similar query in the user's list item componentDidMount to find the match... very good.